# Reversing PWM output

Tags: pwm

For an LED Driver chip I will be using, an inverse PWM signal must be used due to the way I will be wiring it, but could this be established by simply writing a value of (255-Value)-for 8bit PWM or should a NAND chip or other method be used?

Thank You

Comment: write (255 - value) = inversed value, so yes it can be solved in firmware

Comment: I understand that, but will there be any difference at all in the shape of the wave form that can effect the device connected to the signal

Comment: if you are using multiple PWM channels then there might be a difference in waveform phase/alignment between channels if comparing firmware/hardware solutions.

Comment: actualy it would happen in single channel aswell, but in single channel applications I imagine it wouldnt matter.

Comment: Okay, Thank You! So I will interpret that as meaning it has little no no effect

Comment: it just means that depending on how you implement it, you can have "90%" be 10% low first then 90% high or vice versa. In some applications its important to have them start aligned or misaligned. (for example misaligning high pulse starts to ease the load on psu, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this be established by simply writing a value of (255-Value)-for 8bit PWM?

(255 - value) is the best option as it involves no more hardware.

[image]

*Figure 1. PWM signal transitioning from high pulse width (75%) to low (25%) and back again. Note amplitude remains constant.*

PWM switches between V+ and GND. If you invert the logic it will still switches between those two voltages.

> ... or should a NAND chip or other method be used?

If the problem had to be solved without access to the firmware then the NAND gate (wired as an inverter) would be a good solution.